# Redux Form and Semantic UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, semantic-ui

I'm trying to use React-Semantic-UI with Redux Form and making lots of progress but I'm getting the following error.

> Warning: validateDOMNesting(...):  cannot appear as a descendant
>   of .
>       in form (created by Form)
>       in Form (at AddStoreInfoForm.js:57)
>       in form (at AddStoreInfoForm.js:56)
>       in AddStoreInfoForm (created by Form(AddStoreInfoForm))
>       in Form(AddStoreInfoForm) (created by Connect(Form(AddStoreInfoForm)))
>       in Connect(Form(AddStoreInfoForm)) (created by ReduxForm)
>       in ReduxForm (at AddStoreModal.js:27)
>       in div (created by ModalContent)
>       in ModalContent (at AddStoreModal.js:26)
>       in div (created by Modal)

Below is the code. I'm having issues figuring out the best way to use Redux-Form and easily style custom components. Any advice is appreciated, thanks!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Button, Input, Form,  Dropdown, Message, DropDown } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'
//import DatePicker from 'material-ui/DatePicker'

//const dateFormat = require('dateformat')

const options = [
    { key: '1', text: 'New', value: 'New Store' },
    { key: '2', text: 'Minor Remodel', value: 'Minor Remodel'},
    { key: '3', text: 'Major Remodel', value: 'Major Remodel'},
    { key: '4', text: 'Relocation', value: 'Relocation'}
]

class AddStoreInfoForm extends Component {

    renderField = ({input, label, control, options, width, meta: {touched, error} }) => {
        return(
            <div>
                <Form.Field
                    {...input} 
                    control={control}
                    placeholder={label}
                    options={options}
                    width={width}
                    />
                    { touched && error && <span>{error}</span> }
            </div>
        )
    }

    renderDropDown = ({input, width, options, label, meta: {touched, error}}) => {
        return(
            <div>
                <Form.Field>
                    <Dropdown 
                        {...input}
                        onChange={ (param,data) => input.onChange(data.value) }
                        placeholder={label}
                        width={width} 
                        selection 
                        options={options} 
                    />
                </Form.Field>
            </div>
        )
    }

    onSave = (values) => {
        console.log('on save in form', values)
    }

    render() {
        const { handleSubmit } = this.props
        return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSave)}>
                <Form>
                    <Form.Group widths='equal'>
                        <Field name='storeName' label='Store Name' control={Input} component={this.renderField} type='text' />
                        <Field name='storeNumber' label='Store Number' control={Input} component={this.renderField} type='text' />
                        <Field name='remodelType' label='Remodel Type' width={6} options={options} component={this.renderDropDown} />
                    </Form.Group>

                <button type='submit'>Save Store</button>
                </Form>
            </form>
        )
    }


}

const addNewStoreForm = reduxForm({
    form: 'addNewStoreForm'
})(AddStoreInfoForm)

export default addNewStoreForm
```

Comment: Do I need more information or is this just a weird question?

Comment: I think you are missing some nodes while you rendering the form. See for reference : https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4464.